# This-answer-solved-my-problem feature

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When upvoting questions and answers, I do that when I find them useful and/or of high quality. What I sometimes would like, is a way to add some recognition like "this solved my issue as well, thanks for posting!".

One way to do that, is through a comment, but that clutters up the information, and there is even a flag to prevent this (or at least for answers, I'm not sure that it applies to comments too).

But what about a checkbox of sorts with a counter "This solved x people's problems" and then you could actually see who those users are (I'll leave that up to the UX guys on how to do that the best/prettiest). This should only be for actual solutions of concrete problems though.

To extend further on the idea, it could e.g. give bonus points, both to the questioneer for asking a relevant question, and to the answerer for giving an answer that are useful for multiple people.

I'm sure plenty people would argue that that is what the voting is there for to begin with, I'm simply arguing that for me, I'd like to give credit where it is due, on an even more concrete level.

For me, the best comment has been where people say "this solved my problem, thanks!", but that at the same time, clutters up the comments with non-info.

Another way of doing it, is to use the bounty feature, but that has four problems:

1. That you are even able to use the bounty feature as a reward to an existing answer, [is not documented in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), and you do not even see the option until you have spent the reputation points.
2. It will cost at least 50 reputation each time, which for low reputation users like me, quickly would make me loose my priveleges, simply because I wanted to give a heads up to people that their time spent was not just appreciated, but even helped me solve the same issue for me.
3. You can not see the reasoning for the bounty, only the names (that I'm aware of at least).
4. It requires the person to acknowledge it to have at least 75 reputation, and not the standard 15.

So to sum up, I'm proposing this feature for two reasons:

1. To be more concrete on my feedback without having to spam the comments.
2. For me personally, I also find much more value in someone saying "this solved my problem", rather than an upvote, and it would make me more active in re-editing my questions/answers to be of even more use in the future, because I can see it really fixes peoples problems, rather than "nice to know", "well put" or whatever other reasons people have for upvoting.

Comment: You can use a bounty to give an answerer some extra points, if you feel the answer deserved more than an upvote. It will also put a nice "+<amount>" next to the answer.

Comment: "on an even more concrete level" - what's abstract about an upvote?

Comment: @AakashM: I defined that in the beginning "I do that when I find them useful and/or of high quality", so there are many reasons why I would upvote, and therefore the counter isn't "this answer solved my problem", but rather "this answer is of high quality for various reasons".

Answer (score 13):

Don't reinvent the wheel.. just like [S.L. Barth has said already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262588/this-answer-solved-my-problem-feature#comment53212_262588) give it extra credit with a bounty on an existing answer:

> [image]

Comment: This doesn't really achieve the same thing.

Comment: @BenAaronson doesn't really achieve what?

Comment: Well the impression I got was the OP wants it to be something very easy and casual to do. For example, if you have a question about some issue with, say, Visual Studio, you'll often see several different answers, corresponding to different possible causes of the issue. Then in this case, somebody going to that page for the first time would have an immediate gauge of how common each cause is by seeing how many other people had succeess with each attempted solution. Personally I think upvotes serve that purpose fine.

Comment: Want more casual? Use upvote :P

Comment: Usual reward: an upvote. Exceptional reward if the answer **really** help you and is well written: a bounty. Is it that hard? :-)

Comment: @BenAaronson: Edited my question with reasoning as to why this isn't enough/feasible for me, although a decent alternative.

Comment: @Templar Pretty much my feeling. I guess this separates out specifically how often the answer was applicable to people from other things that influence upvotes/downvotes, but really that seems like a very small benefit for a feature like this

Comment: @BenAaronson: The extra benefit I was looking for, was to make the comments more clean. It was just a suggestion though, as I catch myself looking for a feature like that, when an answer has solved my problem.